# DNN Appplication_start in global.asax not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

I have configured some methods to be called in Application_start but Application_start does not seem to be firing at all. Any Info would be greatly appreciated.

I am using DNN 9

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

have you recently done any renaming in your solution?

"clean solution" and "rebuild" doesn't delete assemblies

check Global.asax Inherits="" attribute

something old may be referenced.

Comment: No, I haven't renamed anything lately. It looks like its running but none of my method are being ran or values set. If I create an error and run the site. The error is being hit?

Answer (score 0):

DNN takes over the application instance and this is required for the functionality of DNN. Therefore you can't override Application_Start, it already overrides it with its own inherited class.

I would use an HTTPModule or create scheduled process with the DNN scheduler.

Check these blogs on how to use the HTTP Module which worked for me:
https://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/writing-ihttpmodule-thats-able-to.html
https://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html